# reading parameters into cURL from a text file in bash

Tags: bash, unix, curl, jenkins

I have a following cURL command to execute soapui test in Jenkins. There I am passing two parameters variable1 and variable2.

```
curl --form "project=/build.tool/.jenkins/jobs/$variable1"  --form "suite=$variable2"  host
```

I have a following .txt file where values for those variables are in two columns separated by a space. How do I loop through all those values in my cURL command?

```
#file1.txt
project1.xml TestSuite_1
project1.xml TestSuite_2
project2.xml TestSuite_3
project2.xml TestSuite_4
project3.xml TestSuite_5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Used this on your test input

```
while read p; do
  var1=`echo $p | awk '{print $1" "}'`
  var2=`echo $p | awk '{ print " "$2}'`
  echo $var1
  echo $var2
done <infile
```

Where infile contains your data.

It output:

```
project1.xml
TestSuite_1
project1.xml
TestSuite_2
project2.xml
TestSuite_3
project2.xml
TestSuite_4
project3.xml
TestSuite_5
```

Now you've got them stored in variables, and you can just add them to your `curl` command

```
curl --form "project=/build.tool/.jenkins/jobs/$var1"  --form "suite=$var2"  host
```